# d3.js transition only remove while transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I have a d3.js equirectangular projection with mapped circles. On click on a menu the map changes to an orthographic projection with a transition.
During the transition I want to remove the circles and redraw them on end of the transition. Remove is working but I'm not sure what I have to do to call the circles again.

Here is the code for the change function:

```
      function update(option) {
      var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(option.projection);

        svg.selectAll("path").transition()
              .duration(3000)
              .attr('d', path)
              .each("start", function() { svg.selectAll("circle").remove("circle"); //remove all circles on end
                                  })
              .each("end", function() { svg.append("circle")
                               .attr("circle")
                               .attr("cx", function(d) {
                                  return projection([d.long, d.lat])[0];
                               })
                               .attr("cy", function(d) {
                                  return projection([d.long, d.lat])[1];
                               })
                               .attr("r", function(d) {
                                  if(d.capacity == '-'){return 0}
                                  return rScale(parseInt(d.capacity));  
                               })
                             });
                             }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you generating your circles in the first place? When you're adding your circles again there's no data join, so `d` is always going to be `null` in those callback functions.

Comment: The easiest way to do what you describe is to implement two transitions (one for removing old elements and another for adding new elements). Do you want to remove circles and render them in the new positions? Did you bound data set get updated?

Comment: Instead of removing them altogether, have you considered just hiding them during the transition setting `display:none`? This coud easily be undone after the transition ended.